# Logic for prioritizing records based on a field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, logic

I have a table where list of messages are there which will be displayed on frontend randomly. The message table has one field called 'priority' added recently where i store 3 values 'low','medium','high'. Based on this priority., the number of display of records happen on frontend. Number of times it displayed on frontend also got stored in the same table under field name 'displayed'. Is that possible in mysql query to select records to display based on this 'priority' column and 'number of times displayed' columns some how ? or that has to be done at php level only ?

```
 The older table format:
 ID    MESSAGEHEAD        MESSAGEDESC             DISPLAYED
 1     message title 1    message description 1   15
 2     message title 2    message description 2   17
 3     message title 3    message description 3   16
 and so on....
```

so i have written the following code to fetch messages to display on front end.

```
        // Logic of getting message based on the configuration.
        $messages_query = @mysql_query('select * from c_messages order by displayed asc limit 3');
        if(@mysql_num_rows($messages_query)){
            $total_messages = @mysql_num_rows($messages_query);
            while($message = @mysql_fetch_array($messages_query)){
                $messages_xml .= '<message><messagehead>'.$message['messagehead'].'</messagehead><mesagedesc>'.$message['mesagedesc'].'</mesagedesc></message>';
            }
        }
```

It gives priority to all available messages and show it equally in frontend. Now i have changed database to have one more field called 'priority'.

```
 The new table format:
 ID    MESSAGEHEAD        MESSAGEDESC             DISPLAYED    PRIORITY
 1     message title 1    message description 1   15           HIGH
 2     message title 2    message description 2   17           LOW
 3     message title 3    message description 3   16           MEDIUM
 and so on....
```

Based on the PRIORITY the message should get served on frontend. So the query has to do the logic for fetching records based on this 'priority' and 'displayed' fields.

i mean the display times should be as follows...

```
  MESSAGE        PRIORITY    DISPLAYED
  MESSAGE1     - HIGH      - 45 TIMES
  MESSAGE2     - HIGH      - 45 TIMES
  MESSAGE3     - LOW       - 15 TIMES
  MESSAGE4     - MEDIUM    - 30 TIMES
```

the priority as you seen above decides the number of times the message displayed. Am really sorry i could not able to get a clear idea of how to achieve this. If someone have a logic kindly explain. if you can give a hint on the way i need to proceed i can give try to get it solved. very thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, based on what you say it is possible though no one will help you here if you do not show some effort.

Comment: thanks for your comment and down vote. I have done it by sorting (asc) based on the number of displayed times column and choosing first 3 records to show. it gives equal priority to all records but not sure how to get this priority concept with the another column 'priority'. i could not able to get any from my thinking so y i asked help in here. i did not ask full query. i asked logic if someone can help by where i can start my thinking in that angle to achieve something. anyhow thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: So, edit your question with a little sample data and the query you tried. This will show us that you actually did some effort.

Comment: i have added in question what the code i use for now. hope this may help to trust am asking after doing some effort..

Comment: The best you can do to help yourself to be helped is to provide table schema, sample data and desired outcome.

Comment: Ok i will compile those data and edit the question again. thank you.

Comment: what type is the priority column?

Comment: @peterm - i have posted all the data now. hope i have explained clear at this time. sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Jasen -  the priority column is ENUM type for now. but i can change if that has to be integer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this

```
select * from c_messages order by priority, displayed desc;
```

Or add `desc` after priority if you declared the enum in increasing priority order;

Comment: thank you for helping me. It did not worked as always it considers priority field and only that fields are showing up.

Comment: i mean there are many messages with priority 'HIGH' which is only getting displayed in front... and the displayed count is getting managed between that... i mean the HIGH priority messages displayed count is becoming equal after many executions. the low and medium priority stuffs did not come to screen at all.